QLayerFilter and QObjectPicker doesn't work properly in Qt3D, are there any alternatives?
There is a potential bug in Qt3D that prevents meshes instantiated with different QLayers from functioning properly with a framegraph containing two or more QLayerFilter nodes. But implementing features like transparency typically requires two or more QLayerFilter nodes. Are there alternative methods to pick objects while using multiple QLayerFilter nodes?
I have attached a sample code below. This framegraph includes two QLayerFilter nodes for rendering opaque and transparent objects. Both spheres have a QObjectPicker component attached, but only one sphere with the QLayer component corresponding to the top QLayerFilter node(layerFilterOpaque) in the framegraph can be picked by clicking on it. But if we swap the layerfilter order in the framegraph, then only the other sphere can be picked.
    Qt3DRender::QLayer* opaqueLayer = new Qt3DRender::QLayer;
    opaqueLayer->setRecursive(true);

    Qt3DRender::QLayer* transparentLayer = new Qt3DRender::QLayer;
    transparentLayer->setRecursive(true);

    auto renderSurfaceSelector = new Qt3DRender::QRenderSurfaceSelector;
    renderSurfaceSelector->setSurface(view);

    Qt3DRender::QClearBuffers* clearBuffers = new Qt3DRender::QClearBuffers(renderSurfaceSelector);
    clearBuffers->setBuffers(Qt3DRender::QClearBuffers::AllBuffers);
    clearBuffers->setClearColor(Qt::gray);
    Qt3DRender::QNoDraw* noDraw = new Qt3DRender::QNoDraw(clearBuffers);

    Qt3DRender::QViewport* mainViewport = new Qt3DRender::QViewport(renderSurfaceSelector);
    mainViewport->setNormalizedRect(QRectF(0, 0, 1.0, 1.0));

    Qt3DRender::QCameraSelector* cameraSelector = new Qt3DRender::QCameraSelector(mainViewport);
    cameraSelector->setCamera(view->camera());

    Qt3DRender::QRenderStateSet* renderStateSet = new Qt3DRender::QRenderStateSet(cameraSelector);
    {
        Qt3DRender::QDepthTest* depthTest = new Qt3DRender::QDepthTest;
        depthTest->setDepthFunction(Qt3DRender::QDepthTest::LessOrEqual);
        renderStateSet->addRenderState(depthTest);

        Qt3DRender::QCullFace* cullFace = new Qt3DRender::QCullFace(renderStateSet);
        cullFace->setMode(Qt3DRender::QCullFace::NoCulling);
        renderStateSet->addRenderState(cullFace);
    }

    // Opaque branch - try reversing with layerFilterTransparent. Change order of both filters to reverse them.
    Qt3DRender::QLayerFilter* layerFilterOpaque = new Qt3DRender::QLayerFilter(renderStateSet);
    layerFilterOpaque->addLayer(opaqueLayer);

   // Transparent branch - try reversing with layerFilterOpaque
    Qt3DRender::QLayerFilter* layerFilterTransparent = new Qt3DRender::QLayerFilter(renderStateSet);
    layerFilterTransparent->addLayer(transparentLayer);
    
    view->setActiveFrameGraph(renderSurfaceSelector);
    view->setRootEntity(rootEntity);

    Qt3DCore::QEntity* redSphereEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial* redSphereMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
    {
        Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh* sphereMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh();
        sphereMesh->setRadius(3.0f);
        sphereMesh->setRings(10);
        Qt3DCore::QTransform* sphereTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
        sphereTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(-10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

        redSphereMaterial->setDiffuse(Qt::red);
        Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker* subEntitypicker = new Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker;
        QObject::connect(subEntitypicker, &Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::clicked, [redSphereMaterial](){
            qDebug() << "Red Picked";
        });
        redSphereEntity->addComponent(sphereMesh);
        redSphereEntity->addComponent(sphereTransform);
        redSphereEntity->addComponent(subEntitypicker);
        redSphereEntity->addComponent(redSphereMaterial);
        redSphereEntity->addComponent(opaqueLayer);
        redSphereEntity->setParent(rootEntity);
    }

    Qt3DCore::QEntity* blueSphereEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
    Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial* blueSphereMaterial = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial();
    {
        Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh* sphereMesh = new Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh();
        sphereMesh->setRadius(3.0f);
        sphereMesh->setRings(10);
        Qt3DCore::QTransform* sphereTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
        sphereTransform->setTranslation(QVector3D(10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker* subEntitypicker = new Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker;
        blueSphereMaterial->setDiffuse(Qt::blue);
        QObject::connect(subEntitypicker, &Qt3DRender::QObjectPicker::clicked, [blueSphereMaterial](){
            qInfo() << "Blue Picked";
        });
        blueSphereEntity->addComponent(sphereMesh);
        blueSphereEntity->addComponent(subEntitypicker);
        blueSphereEntity->addComponent(sphereTransform);
        blueSphereEntity->addComponent(blueSphereMaterial);
        blueSphereEntity->addComponent(transparentLayer);
        blueSphereEntity->setParent(rootEntity);
    }


The framegraph works perfectly for handling transparency, hence I cannot go back to use just QSortpolicy. But by using this framegraph, QObjectPicker doesn't work reliably. And I need to click and select objects in my application. How can I pick an object in qt3d without using QObjectPicker while having multiple layer filters in the framegraph?

What version of Qt are you using?

@karlphillip I am using 6.6

Have you considered going back to Qt 5.15.x? This bug will most likely not get fixed, ever. Qt3D will be deprecated in Qt 6.8 and Qt Quick 3D will become the main framework for 3D rendering.

@karlphillip Did this bug not exist in Qt 5.15? If not, do you think it is possible to go back now? The entire application is built using Qt 6.6..

I am not confirming the bug doesn't exist in Qt 5.15.x, I am simply saying it might not. You don't have to port your entire application to Qt 5 to check this out, you just have to write a minimal compilable application with the relevant Qt3D parts to verify this behavior.

Right. I will try it out.
